# spring rest repository resource return single object in search

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I have the following repository exposed as a rest api:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = OrderSummary.class)
public interface OrderRepository extends MongoRepository<Order, Integer>
{
    List<Order> findByOrderNumber(@Param("orderNumber") String orderNumber);
    Order findOneByOrderNumber(@Param("orderNumber") String orderNumber);
}
```

When I go to orders/search i get the expected result:

```
{
"_links" : {
    "findByOrderNumber" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:12345/api/orders/search/findByOrderNumber{?orderNumber,projection}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "findOneByOrderNumber" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:12345/api/orders/search/findOneByOrderNumber{?orderNumber,projection}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:12345/api/orders/search"
    }
  }
}
```

However, only the findByOrderNumber query link works. the findOneByOrderNumber query link returns 404 not found. When I change the returned single `Order` to `List<Order>` it works fine.

If I run the query from code `repository.findOneByOrderNumber()` it works as expected too.

How can I get this to work for a repository rest resource?

#### EDIT:

With some debug logging I could find the following debug log:

```
Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders)]: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource not found!
```

I have tried all sorts of different query names, but this does not seem to be the problem. The problem is with the repository rest resource mapping.

I have tried to return `Optional<Order>` and `Resource<Order>` but neither work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is all just working as intended.

When you do not supply or supply the wrong search parameters and no object is found a 404 error is presented because the resource (The object searched for), could not be found...

Answer (score 2):

You need the follow to get a single (first) element from the query result:

```java
Order findFirstByOrderNumber(@Param("orderNumber") String orderNumber);
```

`find..By..` return a set of records. So if you need to limit it - you can do this with keywords `First` or `Top`: `findTopBy...`, `findFirstBy...`.

More info is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result).

Comment: Unfortunately although you are right and that is how you get a limited result. This does not solve my problem (I tried it anyway, and indeed it does not work). As I indicated, the mongo repository in and of itself works fine. Just the mapping to the repository rest resource is a problem.

Comment: As you see from my post (where I use one, which is also used on the official spring documentation sometimes) the hateoas api shows the endpoint, but it is not mapped correctly and returns 404 when I try to visit it.

Comment: What if you try to use another method that return a single result? For example `findOne`. Will it work?

Comment: findOne is "special" and not mapped to the "search" endpoint but you can use /api/orders/1 (if the id = 1) to find it

Comment: however, any of these queries stop working if I just have them return 1 object (that is, in the rest api, if I call them directly they work fine)

Comment: Just now I implement in my project this method: `@RestResource(path = "byId", rel = "byId") Book findById(@Param("id") Long id);` and it works fine in the rest api. But I have relational DB (H2)...

Comment: That too, does not work when combined with MongoDB repository. I'm going to post a bugreport to spring, see what they come up with...

Answer (score 0):

According to document [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html) you don't need(and maybe shouldn't) to write "One" in method signature. Can u try with method signature?

```
Order findByOrderNumber(@Param("orderNumber") String orderNumber);
```

Comment: This does not make any difference. Was the first thing I tried myself. Note that the mongo repository works just fine, just not the mapping to the repository rest resource